# TypeScript how to wrap function with different generic return type?

Tags: typescript

How to create a higher order function that would turn any function into safe function? By intercepting any errors and returning it as the result?

```
type Errorneous<R> = 
  { is_error: true, message: string } | 
  { is_error: false, value: R }

function dangerous(msg: string): number { 
  throw new Error("not implemented") 
}
console.log(dangerous.to_safe()("Hi"))
```

The code works, but the TypeScript types are not correct as it doesn't check the correctness of arguments and allow invalid calls like `dangerous.to_safe()()` (without arguments).

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nAdhRBXAzgHgEoB8UAvFAFBRQDeUAllgPoQLIBcUwcGEANFALYQsWAIYBzCOyydaKMVAC+UAD7lKNekxZx2AMxEAbLLygA3Q93Z5FZMrowoAxsFqIUUACYi5zTFgAU-FhiUjJyAJTsKBj8AEbM1GocABZIAO5QaBnwSHD+AEQoiMB0-GAGEIIowBAe+eHkCrYeEI4GInDQYgaIsYbUFHTVzPqO0ABiDs6u7lSDlMCIDKK6EDgAgnBiWFAQAB41KB47-v4AdBcd2+zeIADaALoNxES34XyE-vOUKfTspxczlcsOwAAodESCGpwXCbbYEZ5EPDhb6RKAAy5bEFQcFwSEQaGwrEIkhEHLINB+fAIwZNJpkSZOFxuM5gJCLUCQM6LZYiVYkKD2JkzfwNOaURxuaRQYwGXQC4DJehQEQ7W6DTrADCoQVTZkoc6Y64qlD3J4DH4cOAgC2WqCa7WzOiMZi5PSGYx8cwGSwyiByw1ArENJqWpSOETARzJdEQMXfSgOnUaF3adicbh8QTCcSSXZnbOiCQ2MO0sj0yUoLCICpnHpifxeHxIbDcpYrCCigoACVo9RRZH2YGQJUr0tMAoADEA)

```
type Errorneous<R> = 
  { is_error: true, message: string } | 
  { is_error: false, value: R }

function dangerous(msg: string): number { 
  throw new Error("not implemented") 
}

declare global {
  interface Function {
    to_safe<Args extends ((...args: any[]) => any), R>(
      this: ((...args: Parameters<Args>) => R)
    ): ((...args: Parameters<Args>) => Errorneous<R>)
  }
}

Function.prototype.to_safe = function() {
  const self = this as any
  return function(...args: any[]) {
    try {
      return { is_error: false, value: self(...args) }
    } catch (e) {
      return { is_error: true, message: e.message }
    }
  }
}

console.log(dangerous.to_safe()("Hi"))

export const v = 0
```

P.S.

There's a way to do it, but it's not very clean, [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nAdhRBXAzgHgEoB8UAvFAFBRQDeUAllgPoQLIBcUwcGEANFALYQsWAIYBzCOyydaKMVAC+UAD7lKNekxZx2AMxEAbLLygA3Q93Z5FZMrowoAxsFqIUUACYi5zTFgAU-FhiUjJyAJTsKBj8AEbM1GocABZIAO5QaBnwSHD+AEQoiMB0-GAGEIIowBAe+eHkCrYeEI4GInDQYgaIsYbUFHTVzPqO0ABiDs6u7lSDlMCIDKK6EDgAgnyE-sDJ9Oz+-iLs6w3ERHjhkVCHx1CnJEQ5yGh++ATh8xxLK2ubUAAhLYEHZ7LAHI4nPixdgAs4XK4Qu7-GGA+GwbSvbDvT6UBY-ESrDZ8IFQADCwNB+xukPu0NhfEc7DJ6Mu11uUKgqNJTPJ6OeqHQ2MIuJsTTIkycLjcADowEhFqBIDLFstCdBSPYpTN-A05pRHG5pFBjAZdCQUvRBp1gBhUFAtdM3P4Za6OmJwVBvCAANoAXT1X04IAGeLxNrtszojGYuT0hmMfHMBksJogZpdbrgHoaTTDSkcImAjmSNwggbDlAj9o0Me07E43D4gmE4kkUAgMpbogkNnzgyUIiwXpQIDI4sNKCwiAqMp6Yn8Xh8SGwKoJq11BQAErR6p8yBAAB5gZAlSfG0wWgAMQA)

```
declare global {
  interface Function {
    to_safe<A, R>(this: ((a: A) => R)): ((a: A) => Errorneous<R>)
    to_safe<A, B, R>(this: ((a: A, b: B) => R)): ((a: A, b: B) => Errorneous<R>)
    to_safe<A, B, C, R>(this: ((a: A, b: B, c: C) => R)): ((a: A, b: B, c: C) => Errorneous<R>)
  }
}
```

Comment: The second way, after P.S. does not compile

Comment: @captain-yossarian I added link to the playground for the second way, please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) we can infer each element in the array.
See [my article](https://dev.to/captainyossarian/typescript-type-inference-on-function-arguments-2n93) where you can find detailed explanation how to infer it.

```js
type Errorneous<R> =
  { is_error: true, message: string } |
  { is_error: false, value: R }

function dangerous(msg: string): number {
  throw new Error("not implemented")
}

declare global {
  interface Function {
    to_safe<A extends any, Args extends A[], R>(this: ((...args: [...Args]) => R)): ((...args: [...Args]) => Errorneous<R>)
  }
}

Function.prototype.to_safe = function (this: Function) {
  const self = this
  return function <A extends any, Args extends A[]>(...args: [...Args]) {
    try {
      return { is_error: false, value: self(...args) }
    } catch (e) {
      return { is_error: true, message: e.message }
    }
  } as any
}

dangerous.to_safe()("Hi") // ok
dangerous.to_safe()() // error

export const v = 0
```

Comment: @AlexCraft added an explanation